# expression.Name.Name Error 1004 Excel VBA 2016

Tags: excel, vba

The problem is that I want the property Name.Name of the Target range in the Change event as the following Code show

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Left(Target.Name.Name, 6) = "CritFA" Then
        critFA (Target.Name.Name)
    End If
End Sub
```

It works when the cell where I make a change has a Name or TagName (I don't know which is the right way to call them but those are the ones you can create from the Formula Bar), but when the cell doesn't have a TagName gives me Err 1004.

I already tried with `isNull`, `Is Nothing`, and almost everything but, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim nm
    on error resume next
    nm = Target.Name.Name
    on error goto 0
    If Left(nm, 6) = "CritFA" Then
        critFA (Target.Name.Name)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessing `Range.Name` can raise an error if said `Range` is not a named range. I think the scope of `On Error Resume Next` can be limited to it alone.

This works for me:

```
Option Explicit

Private Function GetNameOrNothing(ByVal someRange As Range) As Name
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetNameOrNothing = someRange.Name
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim targetName As Name
    Set targetName = GetNameOrNothing(Target)

    If targetName Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    If Left(targetName.Name, 6) = "CritFA" Then
        critFA targetName.Name
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did similar to what @Tim Williams suggest. It works and solves the problem but I don't feel so comfortable with an error in my code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Left(Target.Name.Name, 6) = "CritFA" Then
        If Err.Number <> 1004 Then
            critFA (Target.Name.Name)
        End If
        Err.Clear
    End If


End Sub
```